# Is it possible to change .cshtml View and see the changes instantly using .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-3.0

**Context**

In my .NET Framework 4.x ASP.NET MVC projects, when using the Visual Studio IDE, it was possible to edit a `.cshtml` view, save, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in the browser and see the change immediately.

This seems to be no longer work in ASP.NET Core applications (using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 3 Preview 5).

**Question**

Is this feature missing in ASP.NET Core? Is this a preview issue? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is something that is no longer enabled *by default* as of ASP.NET Core 3, but it can be re-enabled as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project):

> Runtime compilation is enabled using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package. To enable runtime compilation, apps must:
>
> - Install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) NuGet package.
> - Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`:
>
>   ```
>    services
>        .AddControllersWithViews()
>        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
>   ```

Answer (score 5):

I've marked Kirk's answer as accepted, but maybe this experience could be useful also.

My goal was a "quick edit (cshtml/css/js/ts) then see" iteration.

No need to add and mod anything... I discovered that .NET Core (3) and VS 2019 is so much faster, so in case if we do not want to debug in VS (which is the scenario in most cases when we are changing cshtml/css/js/ts) there is really great iteration:

1. Press ctrl+f5 to launch your web app (no debug) in browser
2. See, test (debug js/ts in Chrome)
3. Edit your cshtml/css/js/ts
4. Press ctrl+shift+b to build (fast!)
5. Switch to your browser and press ctrl+f5 to refresh your page (fast!)
6. Goto 2

Comment: What should this be good for? It's absolutely clear that it will recompile when you restart it. The OP was explicitly asking for a way to recompile while the application is running.